# Tensor Products for Bilinear Optimization?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, nonlinear-optimization, bilinear-form

I'm not very familiar with tensor products, but I recently read in a math textbook that

" Tensor products are very important in algebra. They reduce the study of bilinear maps to the study of linear maps, since a bilinear map out of U ×V is really the same thing as a linear map out of U ⊗ V."

I've been working with an optimization problem that is bilinear in some decision variables, and now I'm wondering if there might be a possibility to use this notion of a Tensor Product to transform a bilinear optimization problem into a linear one? Any thoughts would be nice.